# Obtain name of JCheckBox java

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I try to obtain name of List of JCheckBox but appear a string null. This is my code;

```
JCheckBox mesi [] = {gennaioCheck, febbraioCheck, marzoCheck, aprileCheck, maggioCheck, giugnoCheck,
    luglioCheck, agostoCheck, settembreCheck, ottobreCheck, novembreCheck, dicembreCheck};

    for (JCheckBox m : mesi){
        if (m.isSelected()){
            System.out.println(m.getName());

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean to use `getText()`.

```
System.out.println(m.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is work. I think that getText() doesn't work with checkBox

Comment: @BarbaraPrivitera `getText` will return the text which is displayed on the screen, `getName` will return a name which you apply to it (via `setName`), which can be used when the text is dynamic (or to long to keep typing in). An alternative would be to use `set/getActionCommand`